# Form multiselect item and url encoding with GET method

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form on a Drupal 7 site, which is submitted using the GET method to refresh the page's display using the query parameters.
One of the parameters uses the select box, with the multiple option.  This results in the query parameter using the format option%5B%5D=39&option%5B%5D=54

Is there a way to have the form submit and merge the query parameters into something like option=39+54

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I have working at the moment, although I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

First is that instead of loading the form into my render array with `drupal_get_form()` I have now used `drupal_build_form()` which seems to allow GET method forms to use the validate and submit form hooks.

Then in the submit hook have `$form_state['redirect']` to a custom formatted URL which is cleaner for end users.